# How to display child JSON data in swift 4?

Tags: json, swift, tableview

I have a JSON

```
[ 
  {
  "image": "/images/Home.png",
  "name": "Magazine2",
  "clothe": [
      {
        "nameClothe": "dasdas",
        "imageClothe": "sdvd"
      }
    ]

  },
  {
  "image": "/images/Home.png",
  "name": "Magazine1",
    "clothe": [
      {
        "nameClothe": "dasdass",
        "imageClothe": "sregfd"
      }
      ]
  }
]
```

And i have a struct

```
struct HeroStats:Decodable {
    let image: String
    let name: String
    let clothe: [SecondTable]?
}

struct SecondTable: Decodable {
    let nameClothe: String
    let imageClothe: String
}
```

In first tableView i see "Magazine2" and "Magazine1". Before a click, in the first tableView, i want to see child elements of magazines in second tableView so that the data is relevant. For example - i click `"Magazine2"` and i can see `"nameClothe"` of this

```
"name": "Magazine2",
  "clothe": [
      {
        "nameClothe": "dasdas",
        "imageClothe": "sdvd"
      }
    ]
```

How i can create this? Sorry for my Eng...

Comment: I can display main data in tableView (Magazine1, Magazine2), but i can not display child data of Magazine1 and Magazine 2.

Comment: which problem actually you are facing now, do you want to show your child data in different TableVIew of Different VoewController.

Comment: Does your `Clothe` array data populating properly? Which is inside `Herostate` struct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are populating your `FirstTableView` with `[Herostate]`, now implement `UITableViewDelegate` method
`optional func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` to listen touch event of your `FirstTableView` cell, inside that method prepare your data for `SecondTableView` and performSegue there.
ex:

```
optional func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
     didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
       self.heroesClothes = self.heroes[indexPath.row]
       self.performSegue(withIdentifier "YourSegueIdentifier": String, 
       sender: Any?)
}
```

after that in your `ViewControllers` `prepareForSegue` method's pass data to next `ViewController`
ex:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
if segue.identifier == "yourNextViewControllersIdentifier" {
    if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? SecondViewController{
        destinationVC.heroesClothes = self.heroesClothes 
    }
}
}
```

#### Thank You :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    struct HeroStat: Codable {
    let image: String
    let name: String
    let clothe: [SecondTable]?
}

struct SecondTable: Codable {
    let nameClothe: String
    let imageClothe: String
}
```

and then...

```
let heroStats = try? JSONDecoder().decode([HeroStat].self, from: jsonData)
```

Comment: I have this :) I can display main data in tableView (Magazine1, Magazine2), but i can not display child data of Magazine1 and Magazine 2.

Answer (score 0):

Just try JSON Decoder and you should be ok. Alternatively you can use Swifty JSON, but JSON decoder is nicer in my opinion.

```
        let json = """
{
  "image": "/images/Home.png",
  "name": "Magazine2",
  "clothe": [
      {
        "nameClothe": "dasdas",
        "imageClothe": "sdvd"
      }
    ]

  }

""".data(using: .utf8)!


  let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    do {
        let hero = try decoder.decode(HeroStats.self, from: json)
        print(hero.name)
        print(hero.clothe[0].imageClothe)

    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```